# What is the most rails like way to structure the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using devise for two different types of user in my app. They are called user and professional.

I currently have a simple resource based controller called MessagesController which pulls out messages for the current professional like this

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @messages = Message.find_all_by_profession_id(current_professional.id)
    end
end
```

I want to find the best way of keeping this controller but changing the query based on the type of user that is logged in. I want the same to happen for all actions in the resource (index, new, create, update etc)

I know I can do this

```
if current_user
    @messages = Message.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
else
    @messages = Message.find_all_by_profession_id(current_professional.id)
end
```

but this would be bulky and messy across all actions. I'm sure there must be a better way. What is the most rails like way of doing this? Should I be creating a completely new controller do handle user based messages?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

You can put your code inside the `initialize` method of your controller:

```
def initialize
  if current_user
      @messages = Message.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  else
      @messages = Message.find_all_by_profession_id(current_professional.id)
  end
  super
end
```

Or you can create a `before_filter` :

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_messages
  private
  def get_messages
     if current_user
       @messages = Message.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
     else
       @messages = Message.find_all_by_profession_id(current_professional.id)
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, i think you can move this chunk of code to the model, so the controller only make a call passing the user parameter and gets all messages from the model.

```
# messsages_controller.rb
@messages = Message.find_all_messages(current_user, current_professional)

# message.rb
def self.find_all_messages(user, professional)
  if user
    self.find_all_by_user_id(user.id)
  else
    self.find_all_by_profession_id(professional.id)
  end
end
```

I think it is better for this kind of code to be on your model. Of course you can improve the if/else code, but i am out of ideas now.